# How to create both short and long options for one option in click (python package)?

Tags: python, python-click

How do I specify both a short option and long option for the same option?
e.g., for the following, I also want to use `-c` for `--count`:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--count', default=1, help='count of something')
def my_command(count):
    click.echo('count=[%s]' % count)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_command()
```

e.g.,

```
$ python my_command.py --count=2
count=[2]
$ python my_command.py -c 3
count=[3]
```

References:
[click documentation in a single pdf](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pocoo-click/latest/pocoo-click.pdf)
[click sourcecode on github](https://github.com/pallets/click)
[click website](http://click.pocoo.org/5/)
[click PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/click)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is not well documented, but is quite straight forward:

```
@click.option('--count', '-c', default=1, help='count of something')
```

**Test Code:**

```
@click.command()
@click.option('--count', '-c', default=1, help='count of something')
def my_command(count):
    click.echo('count=[%s]' % count)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_command(['-c', '3'])
```

**Result:**

```
count=[3]
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you @Stephen_Rauch!